# netezza delete records with different timestamp field where specific fields are the same

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a netezza table where data can get overlapped when updated however a `timestamp` field on each associated would be different.  For instance:

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----+
|       ts        | first_nm |   last_nm   | val |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----+
| 4/1/2015 4:15pm | ben      | bloomington | 12  |
| 4/1/2015 4:20pm | ben      | bloomington | 4.5 |
| 4/1/2015 4:20pm | andrew   | bloomberg   | 2.8 |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----+
```

Id like to keep the following records and delete the earlier timestamp for ben bloomington:

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----+
|       ts        | first_nm |   last_nm   | val |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----+
| 4/1/2015 4:20pm | ben      | bloomington | 4.5 |
| 4/1/2015 4:20pm | andrew   | bloomberg   | 2.8 |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----+
```

so, based on `first_nm` and `last_nm` being distinct how can I just keep the latest ts with the latest value?

I think I could use `row_number()` function but I am unsure how to implement this in my `delete` statement.

Comment: can you do something like this - create table t2 as select MAX(ts) ts, first_nm, last_nm from t1 group by first_nm, last_nm; if you don't have ID on your table?

Comment: i was thinking of doing something like that with a temp table and then dropping the table and re-inserting the records, however as this table grows i was worried it may become unperformant although i guess i'm not sure.

Comment: As your table grows a truncate replace strategy could create a large amount of data for the dba doing nightly incremental backups.  So deleting only the records that you care about should keep the dba's happy.

Comment: eek, yeah i was worried about something like that, thanks @niederee!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete all rows that aren't the latest timestamp using the example below. I added the windowed function `row_number()` as an example.

```
delete from <table>
where rowid in
   (
select rwid
from (  select rowid as rwid
        , row_number() over(partition by first_nm,last_nm order by ts desc) as rown
        from <table>
     ) sub
where sub.rown>1
   );
```

Comment: `rowid` is an internal column that is unique to each row of data.  [rowid documentation](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_data_types_ntz_internal.html)

Answer (score 1):

The shorter solution that should do the same is:

```
 DELETE FROM table t
 WHERE 
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table 
           WHERE t.rwid < rwid 
             AND t.first_nm = first_nm 
             AND t.last_nm = last_nm)
```